# FOREIGN KEY references same table's column. Can't insert values

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascade

I created table with FOREIGN KEY and can't insert anything.

```
CREATE TABLE menus (

id int(10),
parent_id int(10),
label varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES menus (id)
);
```

I need FOREIGN KEY to automatically delete children when parent was deleted. This table was successfully created but I can't insert anything.

```
INSERT INTO `menus` (`parent_id`, `label`)
VALUES ('1', 'label1');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `menus` (`label`)
VALUES ( 'label1');
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I really don't want look for any children in php code so I need somehow create simple table with 3 columns and automatically drop all children and they children too.

Comment: You say you want to "automatically delete children", yet all you show us are the inserts. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Typically, you will need to allow the 'root' record to have a null parent - i.e. `menus.parent_id` should be nullable, and the 'root' menu item will have a null `parent_id`.

Comment: what values do you want to have for id? I didn't see any of them inserted or autogenerated

Comment: I think you missed the autoincrement on id column

Answer (score 10):

For all your needs you should take this structure

```
CREATE TABLE `menus` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_parent_menu` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_menu` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) 
    REFERENCES `menus` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5b5d/1/0)

Demo shows inserting and deleting of a parent node

The magic drop part for all children is done by `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: @SirRufo It doesn't work for `update`. check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/445052/1/0 and then try adding `Update menus set id = 6 WHERE id = 1;` you will get `#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row`

Comment: @Sam It doesn't work for updating the identity field. Why do you ever want to update/change the value of an autogenerated identity field?

Comment: @SirRufo Completely agree with you that in practical situations PK is never updated. Just wanted to add this comment to mention that this is a known [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) limitation (or [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24668) ) in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you will need to allow the 'root' record to have a null parent - i.e. `menus.parent_id` should be nullable, and the 'root' menu item will have a null `parent_id`.

i.e.

Change your DDL to:

```
 parent_id int(10) NULL
```

And then you add your root element with NULL as the parent_id

```
insert into `menus` (id, `label`, parent_id)
VALUES (1, 'label1', null);
```

Then you are good to go with child elements:

```
insert into `menus` (id, `label`, parent_id)
VALUES (2, 'subitem1', 1);
```

etc.

[SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9355/1)

Comment: The `parent_id` is already nullable (by default). The error is correctly as you say, in the insert code.

Comment: this is just only half, auto deleting of childs is missing :o)