# SQL Can't create table errno 150

Tags: mysql, innodb

I made an ERD with MySQL Workbench and now I'm trying to import it,

The first table it tries to create it errors.

The sql:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`catagories` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `catagory` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `order` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_catagory_idx` (`catagory` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catagory`
    FOREIGN KEY (`catagory`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`catagories` (`catagory`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

## 1005 - Can't create table 'db.catagories' (errno: 150)

both catagory and ID have an index, are the same, but it still throws this error, any thoughts?

Comment: its an foreing key error, i think it have something to do with the :  `FOREIGN KEY (`catagory`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`catagories` (`catagory`)` (trying to make the relation  from the table to the same table)

Comment: @Youness , I want to have sub-catagories, in mysql it's allowed to have references to the same table - Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138952/foreign-key-references-same-tables-column-cant-insert-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your foreign key constraint is invalid,
column catagory references to itself.

Edit: answer to comment below.

If you want to reference a parent category, reference id field.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`catagories` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `parent_catagory` INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  `order` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_catagory_idx` (`parent_catagory` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_catagory`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_catagory`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`catagories` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: That's what I want it to do :)
A catagory can be a sub-catagory

Comment: I ws referencing to the wrong column, stupid mistake, thanks!